# How to identify and check Validation Controls in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a form with `TextBox` elements each being associated with a `RequiredFieldValidator`, `RegularExpressionValidator` or both. Every validation control has `SetFocusOnError="true"` and `Display="None"`, but none of them have `ErrorMessage`. This way, when a validator fails, the `TextBox` gets focused, and at that moment, I have to find that `TextBox` and highlight it in `red` (so that the user will see the error).

Here goes my JS:

```
$("input").change(function() {
    // Validate the whole page:
    Page_ClientValidate();

    if (Page_IsValid) {
        alert("Validation successful!");
    }
    else {
        // Loop thru each <input> and highlight them in red (.error) or green (.success):
        $("input").each(function() {
            // Get validator associated with $(this) input:
            var validator = ??? // using ControlToValidate maybe?

            if (validator has failed validation) ??? {
                $(this).addClass("error"); // $(this) -> current input
            }
            else {
                $(this).addClass("success");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I don't know how to do is in `???`. Again, CSS is just `.error {color:red}` and `.success {color:green}`.

**PROBLEM**:

#### 1. **How can I get the validation control associated with the current input?**

#### 2. **How can I check that the validator control has failed validation?**

**NOTE**:

- I'd like to use native ASP.NET validation controls rather than rewrite the whole validation logic on the client side manually. So `EnableClientScript="False"` is NOT an option
- Everything is done on the front-end in JavaScript, not in code-behind file! At the same time, I can use `<%= %>` tags to access `ClientID` for example.

### Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1520193/determine-what-controls-are-failing-on-a-asp-net-web-page#answer-1520657) helped me solve the problem. Basically, I ended up doing this:

```
var input = $(event.target);
// Get validators based on this input's 'data-ctrl' attribute:
var validators = $("." + input.attr("data-ctrl"));
validators.each(function () {
     // RegExValidator does NOT fail on whitespace, so check that <input> is non-empty;
     // Don't have to do it on every single validator btw...
     if (!(this).isvalid || !input.val())
         input.removeClass("success").addClass("error");
     else
         input.removeClass("error").addClass("success");
});
```